# Specific colors for multiple surface plot

Tags: r, colors, plotly

Take the example from https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/ for multiple surfaces. Here is the code of this example.

```
library("plotly")
z <- c(
  c(8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87),
  c(8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92),
  c(8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91),
  c(8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92),
  c(8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92),
  c(8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92),
  c(8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92),
  c(8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94),
  c(8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99),
  c(8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11),
  c(8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11),
  c(9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27),
  c(9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2),
  c(8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19),
  c(8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18)
)
dim(z) <- c(15,6)
z2 <- z + 1
z3 <- z - 1

fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z2, opacity = 0.98)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z3, opacity = 0.98)
```

How can I make each surface a specific color? i.e. the first surface be all red, the second blue and so on.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument `colorscale`, as the following:

```
fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(107,184,255)","rgb(0,90,124)")) )
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z2, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(255,107,184)","rgb(128,0,64)")))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z3, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(107,255,184)","rgb(0,124,90)")))
fig
```

For each surface, you specify two colors: a darker and a lighter one. The contrast between them correspond to different heights of each surface. The heights of surfaces are scaled between 0 and 1. The pair of colors specified are assigned to respective bottom and top heights of each surface.

You can play with shades of RGB colors to get exactly the colors you want. Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_rgb.asp) or [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html) sites for more information on RGB color scales.

[image]

My code was adapted from [this page](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-different-color-scales-for-multiple-surfaces/6153/3), which worked with a very similar example from yours, but only two surfaces.

Based on the same logic, you can expand the number of layers, as requested in the comments:

```
z4 <- z + 2 
z5 <- z + 3 
z6 <- z + 4

fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(107,184,255)","rgb(90,90,124)")) )
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z2, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(255,107,184)","rgb(128,0,64)")))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z3, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(107,255,184)","rgb(0,124,90)")))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z4, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(182,142,242)","rgb(104,3,255)")))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z5, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(247,226,157)","rgb(255,192,7)")))
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z6, opacity = 0.98, colorscale = list(c(0,1),c("rgb(129,212,247)","rgb(12,177,247)")))
fig
```

The above code produced:

[image]

Comment: I somehow can't figure out how to add colors. I have 5 layers and when I am trying to add colors from the websites you have referenced, my whole plot just messes up.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Share your new code (and data, if the case) for the plot with 5 layers, so we can try to figure out what the problem is. The code I posted worked with the example you shared.

Comment: I am confused on the part how to define the lower part and upper part colors. I mean how to get the combination. In this same example take ```z4 <- z+2``` , ```z5 <- z+3``` and ```z6 <- z+4```. How to define colors for these?

Comment: So how did you figure out the other colors? I mean the combinations

Comment: Yes, from the second link I shared to you. I pick up a general color on the right vertical bar, then I choose two differents shades of the same color, one lighter and one darker, and fill the rgb codes in the appropriate places... I updated the answer with your request