# Multi-layer 3D surface with plotly

Tags: r, 3d, plotly

for the following data I am trying to create a 3D surface plot with x=alpha, y=lambda and z=RMSE. For each gamma I want to have on separate surface in the graph. I tried the following code to create the first layer. However, all I get is a white graph with a z axis limited to [0;1]. I have tried to use several codes that I found online, but none of it worked.

```
 data <- data.frame(
        RMSE = c(
            19238769.80, 19238769.80, 19238769.80, 19238769.80, 19238769.80,
            19238769.80, 19238769.80, 19238769.80, 19238769.80, 19238769.80,
            1516996.35, 1603109.25, 1701684.26, 1692241.66, 1728254.06,
            1767298.32, 1840967.14, 1873057.87, 1925787.28, 1922243.27,
            1925263.54, 906742.04, 918061.83, 1170369.15, 1030938.54,
            886937.19, 900514.10, 894224.88, 603581.98, 620510.60,
            609132.61, 619806.55, 58965.11, 86155.05, 82149.93, 80818.37,
            82439.19, 71869.52, 71822.20, 62062.51, 40120.85, 39089.10,
            26557.80
        ),
        alpha = c(
            0.96, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06,
            0.98, 0.99, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09,
            0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.50, 0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.54, 0.55, 0.56,
            0.76, 0.77, 0.78, 0.79, 0.80, 0.81, 0.82, 0.83, 0.84, 0.85, 0.86
        ),
        lambda = c(
            0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01,
            0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04, 0.04,
            0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51, 0.51,
            0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81, 0.81
        ),
        gamma = c(rep(2.1, 25),rep(2.0,18))
    )
    
     fig <- plot_ly(x = data$alpha, y = data$lambda, z = data$RMSE,type="surface")
    fig
```

Comment: In additionto DaveAmstrong answer, here is a link with another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921694/specific-colors-for-multiple-surface-plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polly's surface plot wants a vector of unique x-axis values for `x` and unique y-axis values for `y`.  The `z` argument should be a matrix with values that correspond to the combinations of the `x` and `y` values.  Here's an example:

```r
alpha <- seq(0,1, by=.01)
lambda <- seq(0,1,by=.01)
gamma <- c(1,2)
z1 <- outer(alpha, lambda, \(x,y)x*y + gamma[1])
z2 <- outer(alpha, lambda, \(x,y)x*y + gamma[2])

library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=alpha, y=lambda) %>% 
  add_surface(z=z2, colorscale = "Greens") %>% 
  add_surface(z=z1, colorscale = "Blues")
```

[image]

---

#### Answering Comments

In the comments, the OP asked if there are other options. `wireframe()` in the `lattice()` package takes data of this format, but there's simply not enough data there to generate the plot.  Perhaps this is a toy example, but if you made a heat map of where you actually have data, you would see that it's very sparse and unilkely that a 3-D surface plot of just these data would be all that enlightening:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=alpha, y=lambda, fill=RMSE)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  facet_wrap(~gamma, ncol=2) +  
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This means that I cant really use plot_ly as the vectors dont have unique values. Do you have any suggestions on how to graph the given vectors?

Comment: @Joe94 I updated the answer to address your comment.